# CSS dynamic margin?

Tags: html, css, less

edit: I added a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ocruzwrt/
basically the green square must stay vertically centered without changing html..

I'm working on a project, basically its an old website and it must be adapted for mobile. Of course a lot of things would require to be written from scratch but I can't do that, I don't have enough time.

So I'm facing a huge problem aligning vertically an icon menu that has been designed as an empty div with a sprite background, while the container's height is constantly smaller.

Unfortunately, I can't use these for various reasons :

- flexbox
- display table
- absolute positionning

I was left with that solution.. it more or less keep the icon centered vertically at all time : (please be aware its written in LESS)

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        #menu-mobile-top {#menu-mobile-btn {margin-top: 2.5%}}
}
    @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
        #menu-mobile-top {#menu-mobile-btn {margin-top: 2%}}
}
    @media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
        #menu-mobile-top {#menu-mobile-btn {margin-top: 1%}}
}
    @media only screen and (max-width: 350px) {
        #menu-mobile-top {#menu-mobile-btn {margin-top: 0%}}
}
```

But it's badly written. Is there any way to write this better ? Ideally I start at 2.5% at 600 and end at 0% at 350.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use two IDs in your CSS selector? you could simplify it to `#menu-mobile-btn { margin-top: x%; }`.

Comment: that's correct, I just reused the old selectors without after thought

Comment: do you have an example on JsFiddle etc. Atleast the code (html)

Comment: done one https://jsfiddle.net/ocruzwrt/

Answer (score 0):

If you wrote it in css, you were right: it is badly written. This is corrected:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: {
    600px) {
        #menu-mobile-top > #menu-mobile-btn;
    }
    500px) {
        #menu-mobile-top > #menu-mobile-btn;
    }
    400px) {
        #menu-mobile-top > #menu-mobile-btn;
    }
    350px) {
        #menu-mobile-top > #menu-mobile-btn;
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, it is in LESS, not css, forgot to tell in my post

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

https://jsfiddle.net/j3u5282d/

```
.spacer {
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 5%; /* speed of expanding */
}
```